# How to call numpy/scipy C functions from Cython directly, without Python call overhead?

Tags: python, optimization, numpy, scipy, cython

I am trying to make calculations in Cython that rely heavily on some numpy/scipy mathematical functions like `numpy.log`. I noticed that if I call numpy/scipy functions repeatedly in a loop in Cython, there are huge overhead costs, e.g.:

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
np.import_array()
cimport cython

def myloop(int num_elts):
   cdef double value = 0
   for n in xrange(num_elts):
     # call numpy function
     value = np.log(2)
```

This is very expensive, presumably because `np.log` goes through Python rather than calling the numpy C function directly. If I replace that line with:

```
from libc.math cimport log
...
# calling libc function 'log'
value = log(2)
```

then it's much faster. However, when I try to pass a numpy array to libc.math.log:

```
cdef np.ndarray[long, ndim=1] foo = np.array([1, 2, 3])
log(foo)
```

it gives this error:

```
TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

My questions are:

1. Is it possible to call the C function and pass it a numpy array?  Or can it only be used on scalar values, which would require me to write a loop (eg if I wanted to apply it to the `foo` array above.)
2. Is there an analogous way to call scipy functions from C directly without a Python overhead? Which how can I import scipy's C function library?

Concrete example: say you want to call many of scipy's or numpy's useful statistics functions (e.g. `scipy.stats.*`) on scalar values inside a `for` loop in Cython? It's crazy to reimplement all those functions in Cython, so their C versions have to be called. For example, all the functions related to pdf/cdf and sampling from various statistical distributions (e.g. see http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.rv_continuous.pdf.html#scipy.stats.rv_continuous.pdf and http://www.johndcook.com/distributions_scipy.html) If you call these functions with Python overhead in a loop, it'll be prohibitively slow.

thanks.

Comment: The `scipy.stats` pdf etc. functions are mainly implemented in Python. You can avoid overhead by processing many numbers at once.

Comment: I just found this post as I have a very similar problem. I've cythonized my loops, but there are numpy and scipy calls within the loops, so I'm not seeing any speedup over default Python. Seeing that it's impractical to re-write numpy and scipy functions, this seems to make the value proposition of cython a lot less attractive than I had originally hoped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot apply C functions such as log on numpy arrays, and numpy does not have a C function library that you can call from cython.

Numpy functions are already optimized to be called on numpy arrays. Unless you have a very unique use case, you're not going to see much benefit from reimplementing numpy functions as C functions. (It's possible that some functions in numpy are not implemented well, in chich case consider submitting your importations as patches.) However you do bring up a good point.

```
# A
from libc.math cimport log
for i in range(N):
    r[i] = log(foo[i])

# B
r = np.log(foo)

# C
for i in range(n):
    r[i] = np.log(foo[i])
```

In general, A and B should have similar run times, but C should be avoided and will be much slower.

Update

Here is the code for scipy.stats.norm.pdf, as you can see it's written in python with numpy and scipy calls. There is no C version of this code, you have to call it "through python". If this is what is holding you back, you'll need to re-implant it in C/Cython, but first I would spend some time very carefully profiling the code to see if there are any lower hanging fruit to go after first.

```
def pdf(self,x,*args,**kwds):
    loc,scale=map(kwds.get,['loc','scale'])
    args, loc, scale = self._fix_loc_scale(args, loc, scale)
    x,loc,scale = map(asarray,(x,loc,scale))
    args = tuple(map(asarray,args))
    x = asarray((x-loc)*1.0/scale)
    cond0 = self._argcheck(*args) & (scale > 0)
    cond1 = (scale > 0) & (x >= self.a) & (x <= self.b)
    cond = cond0 & cond1
    output = zeros(shape(cond),'d')
    putmask(output,(1-cond0)+np.isnan(x),self.badvalue)
    if any(cond):
        goodargs = argsreduce(cond, *((x,)+args+(scale,)))
        scale, goodargs = goodargs[-1], goodargs[:-1]
        place(output,cond,self._pdf(*goodargs) / scale)
    if output.ndim == 0:
        return output[()]
    return output
```

Comment: But what if I need to write a for loop in code that can't be vectorized, and I want to use certain numpy functions (on scalar values, not vectors) in that loop? Would I have to reimplement those numpy functions in Cython? It seems very silly. I can do it only with option C, which as you noted, is not a good one

Comment: In that case you're best option might be re-implement those functions in cython and use option A. If you don't mind my asking, which numpy functions do you need to call inside your loop.

Comment: Various functions related to statistics. I edited my answer to have more details. For example, all the functions related to pdf/cdf and sampling from various statistical distributions (e.g. see http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.rv_continuous.pdf.html#scipy.stats.rv_continuous.pdf and http://www.johndcook.com/distributions_scipy.html). It doesn't seem right to reimplement all those pdfs using primitives from libc.math just to get it in Cython... must be better way?

Comment: You probably have access to a lot of element-wise ufuncs in numpy.